# How did you benefit from Resharper

Tags: resharper

How much code kludge could you remove using the resharper 4?

I want to hear more about benefits on 10k+ codebases

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resharper is a tool. Continuous refactoring is an attitude. If you've got the attitude, then IMO resharper is the best tool you can get. The tool by itself does not really remove any kludge.

The size of the codebase only makes these tools more important. With reasonably large codebases you have to trust the tool. I use all og jetbrains' tools and think they're marvellous.

I still think continuous refactoring is best introduced into a project by getting one or more people who know *all the tricks* into your team(s).

And yes. I worked on a stuck project for 7 months doing *only* refactoring, using resharper. I basically refactored almost every single line of code. Maybe it should have been rewritten from scratch, but that was not an option. Be sure to introduce testing as you refactor.

Answer (score 2):

It's freaking awesome. I'm currently working on releases for the large code base we're working on here and to merge a change across two branches is utterly awesome.

CTRL + T => Means I can find a type in no time at all. To go to SmartcardProductIssueService is just CTRL+T, SPIS, ENTER and the file is opened. SHIFT+ALT+L and it's selected in the SolutionExplorer, then I just right click to view the history and I can start working on the merge.

Refactoring is nice and the "greyed out" effect for unused code has helped me spot a few bugs.

If you want to see some of the refactoring joy check out the [jedi refactoring vid](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Resharper offers so many benifits in terms of developer productivity. It also improves better design by suggesting many improvements to the code on the fly. i have been encouraging people in my team to use all the shortcuts from Resharper and try and get off the habit of using mouse. Its not to say that you shouldn't be using mouse at all. But Resharper offers so many rich features that as a developer you can almost forget to make use of mouse.

Here is a small blog post I wrote about how to make use of resharper to clean code 
http://nileshgule.blogspot.com/2010/10/refactoring-clean-code-using-resharper.html(This does require few mouse clicks here and there :))

There are various addins for resharper like Stylecop, NUnit etc which help other tools integrate with resharper and offer better user (developer) experience.

Hope this helps.